# Too many redirect on laravel middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have created a custom middleware and i am checking if the password field is null and redirect user to change the password but it give me redirection error, any one can help? Let me add more details i want user to redirect to /change-password if the password field is empty

**so here's the whole process.**

user verify the email, redirect to /change-password route instead of dashboard if password field in the database is empty other wise we redirect them to dashboard. Users shouldn't access any route until they didn't update the password.

**Remember i am using laravel breeze for auth**

**Middleware code:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ChangePasswordMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (empty($user->password)){
            return redirect()->route('patient.password');
        } else{
            return  redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**My Routes:**

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'changepassword'])->group(function (){
   Route::get('/change-password', [PatientsController::class, 'passwordView'])->name('patient.password');
   Route::get('/dashboard', [PatientsController::class, 'index'])->name('patient.dashboard');
   Route::get('pricing', [PatientsController::class, 'pricing'])->name('patient.pricing');
});
```

changepassword is registered in my kernel.php and it's a custom middleware.

i have tried to create a different group for routes but it still doesn't work, i want changepassword middleware to force use to change the password and other routes shouldn't work until the password field is updated

Comment: your middleware has a logic of " if(true) redirect else redirect ". no wonder when you use it, the only result is a redirection. the `return $next($request);` statement is never reached.

Comment: If the password is empty it will also redirect to `patient.password` even if that's the current route being accessed leading to infinite redirects to the same URL

Comment: @N69S how can I resolve the issue? I am new to laravel

Comment: @apokryfos so how could I resolve the issue? Any help

Comment: The route `patient.password` should be excluded from the middleware. Either put this route outside of route group or try excluding it. Take a look here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#excluding-middleware

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen but I want to check password with the middleware, can’t we use middleware for checking if a field is empty or not and then redirect user to the different route based on that condition?

Comment: You're right. But the catch is. The route you want to redirect the user to after checking for `empty` password needs to be outside of the middleware. Otherwise the middleware falls into a loop. `Empty password --> goToRoute --> Again empty password --> goToRoute .... `. I hope I am clear.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen so my middleware code is right issue is with the route code if so can you send me a code how to fix it?

Comment: I can't say if it is logically correct. I noticed the obvious flaw and pointed out. I will try help and resolve the flaw in the answer.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen thankyou so much. Looking forward for your answer. Remember I want my middleware to force user to add password after email verification. So the routes will not work until the password is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if (empty($user->password)){
        abort(302, 'Please change your password', ['Location' => route('patient.password')]);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

If the password is empty, it automatically redirects to `/change-password` route.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the middleware is being called over and over because the password is empty. Hence, the issue of too many redirects. Your routes must ignore the route for /change-password.

```
    Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'changepassword'])->group(function (){
       Route::get('/change-password', [PatientsController::class, 'passwordView'])
          ->name('patient.password')
          ->withoutMiddleware([\App\Http\Middleware\ChangePasswordMiddleware::class]);
       ...
       ...
    });
```

After this your too many redirects problem should go away.

Also, make sure your if/else logic is correct in the `handle()` method. The `else` logic looks odd to me.